# Is there a way to import flash into XML or JAVA for an android app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, flash, button

I am developing an app for android in eclipse IDE, and I was wondering if there is a way to import anything I did in flash into my app. I have just made a simple button in flash, so is there a way to import this into my application in eclipse.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could try exporting from Adobe Flash into SVG and loading at least the graphics using e.g. http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/ -- as for animations and ActionScript, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to run ActionScript or any Flash animations in native android.  You can attempt to replicate the behavior, however, using the same graphics and the available android libraries.  I recommend creating an object that inherits the `Button` class in android and going from there.

EDIT: I did some googling and found this: http://code.google.com/p/java-actionscript-api-for-android/ , but this will not solve your problem directly.